# A question about definition about Riemann curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a paper and it defined Riemann curvature as [image: definition in paper]

where the surface equation :$x^{a}=f^{a}(u,v)$
However, I am confused because it is different from traditional definition :[image: Traditional definition]

in this paper ‘ definition there are two partial derivatives terms after Riemann curvature on right side of equation 2.  I wonder are these two definition same?

Comment: What you have in the image is not the definition of curvature but what physicists  call Ricci commutation relations for covariant derivatives. And yes, the $R$ on the right is the usual curvature tensor with one index raised.

Comment: Thanks my dude , I don’t find the Ricci commutation in google , could it derive from definition of Riemann curvature, I would be happy if you could provide some reference

Comment: Yes, this is physicists' jargon. See e.g. formula (7) in [Bailey, Lagrangian Dynamics of Spinning Particles](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103898967) or [Israel, Relativity, Astrophysics and Cosmology, p. 46](https://books.google.com/books?id=jyn4CAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: Thanks for your reference !  And I am reading your first paper and I am confused about where Λ from in eq(1). I think it is different from the traditional definition of tensor transformation